# Nginx cache a path

Tags: caching, nginx

Below is my config

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=10m  max_size=1g;
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://domainserver.com:8000;
                proxy_connect_timeout       600;
                proxy_send_timeout          600;
                proxy_read_timeout          600;
                send_timeout                600;
        }
}
```

I want to cache all the urls which have /ads/ in it

so URL like following will be cached

http://domain.com/ads/my-first-ad
http://domain.com/ads/my-seconnd-ad

Answer (score 0):

I added following and it worked

```
location /ads/ {
        proxy_pass http://domainserver.com:8000;
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_key "$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args";
        proxy_cache_valid 30d;
        proxy_cache_valid any 10s;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error invalid_header timeout updating;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        expires 30d;
}
```